# How could I automatically create a network share of every USB drive on Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, smb

I'd like to create a "network USB hub", a central device, where all the coworkers plug all the USB drives, and then everyone can access them.

I wonder how I could set (headless) Ubuntu to automatically mount and share on SMB all the USB drives.

Comment: Might get an answer faster on unix.stackexchange.com,

Comment: If [this method](http://www.davidc.net/automatically-exporting-usb-drives-over-samba) is suitable I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: @harrymc look suitable. I hope it won't be too hard to implement with a rpi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procedure below is described in greater detail in the article
[Automatically exporting USB drives over Samba](http://www.davidc.net/automatically-exporting-usb-drives-over-samba):

The tool used is `usbmount`, which is called when a USB disk is inserted to
mount the disk. It executes the scripts in `/etc/usbmount/mount.d` using `run-parts`
and `/etc/usbmount/umount.d` upon disconnection.

**smb.conf**

Create the empty directory `/etc/samba/auto` and add these lines at the end of
`smb.conf`:

```
include = /etc/samba/auto/usb0.conf
include = /etc/samba/auto/usb1.conf
include = /etc/samba/auto/usb2.conf
include = /etc/samba/auto/usb3.conf
include = /etc/samba/auto/usb4.conf
include = /etc/samba/auto/usb5.conf
include = /etc/samba/auto/usb6.conf
include = /etc/samba/auto/usb7.conf
```

**mount.d**

To automatically create the above configuration files when a drive is inserted,
create this file as `/etc/usbmount/mount.d/50_add_samba_export`, chmod as executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHARENAME=`basename $UM_MOUNTPOINT`
cat > /etc/samba/auto/$SHARENAME.conf <<EOF
[$SHARENAME]
   comment = $UM_VENDOR $UM_MODEL
   path = $UM_MOUNTPOINT
   read only = no
EOF
 
/etc/init.d/samba restart
```

**umount.d**

To remove the share when the disk is unmounted or removed, add in
`/etc/usbmount/umount.d/50_remove_samba_export`, chmod as `+x`:

```
#!/bin/bash
SHARENAME=`basename $UM_MOUNTPOINT`
rm -f /etc/samba/auto/$SHARENAME.conf
 
/etc/init.d/samba restart
```

**Tidying up**

To handle the case of a reboot without previously cleanly unmounting,
create a boot script to clear out `/etc/samba/auto`.
Use an init script, say `/etc/init.d/auto-share-clean`:

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          auto-share-clean
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Cleans auto samba shares
### END INIT INFO
 
rm -f /etc/samba/auto/*
```

Then:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/auto-share-clean
update-rc.d auto-share-clean defaults
```